# How I can change my organization with flexbox only mobile version

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In desktop version i have 3 divs side by side but in mobile version i would like to have 1 div on top and 2 div side by side how can i go about this with current code? do I have to make a hidden div in desktop version and display in mobile version?

I have drawn an example just below to explain what I want.
thank youu.

[image: desktop to mobile]

```css
body,
html,
main {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.main-content {
  background: url('assets/img/pain.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.middle-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: center center;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}

div.logo-image-content img {
  width: 500px;
}

div.logo-image-content {
  padding-top: 55px;
  margin: auto;
}

.middle-content-paragraph {
  font-size: 20px;
}



@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  div.logo-image-content img {
    width: 850px;
  }

  .middle-content-paragraph {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .middle-content {
    border: none;
  }

  .middle-content-title {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <div class="logo-image-content">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="middle-content">
    <div class="middle-content-text">
      <h2 class="middle-content-title">Adresse</h2>
      <p class="middle-content-paragraph">bla bla road <br> 75000 Paris</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-content-text">
      <h2 class="middle-content-title">Horaires</h2>
      <p class="middle-content-paragraph">Lundi au Dimanche 7h - 20h30 <br> Fermeture Mecredi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-content-text">
      <h2 class="middle-content-title">Téléphone</h2>
      <p class="middle-content-paragraph">XX XX XX XX XX</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-content">
    <h2 class="bottom-content-title">
      Ici il y aura bientot un text ...
    </h2>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: which one is supposed to be on top ? logo ?

Comment: You might consider using grid

Comment: I have three divs address, horaire, telephone, I want the address at the top of the horaire and the telephone below. thank you

Comment: Hey @Richard I updated my answer, that should do the trick. si vous avez d'autres questions ou si le code marche pas, je suis dispo cdt

Comment: codepen pour voir leffet est ici https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/eYzzbVX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media queries to limit CSS instructions only to some smaller screen devices. You can use the screen width like this.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:780px) {
    .middle-content-text {
     width:45%;
    margin:0 2.5%!important;
}
 .middle-content-text:nth-child(1) {
     width:95%!important;
}
 .middle-content {
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:center;
     width:80%;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
 .middle-content-text {
     width:45%;
    margin:0 2.5%!important;
}
 .middle-content-text:nth-child(1) {
     width:95%!important;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm almost there I would like to schedule and phone side by side not in column. 
 thank you @LaurentC

Comment: just updated i had not seen that requirement looked at your question too fast :)

Comment: yes it works it's been 2 days that I was on it.  thank you

Comment: np! glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex direction column in mobile using media query. First one set width 100% and last two div set 50% width each one. If you need  gap between last two div then set 48% or whatever you need then set margin left and right auto.